# Is there a YouTube API that can give me structured metadata about a video?

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, freebase

Using the YouTube API, how can I fetch structured data about a video? For instance, given a video that is a movie trailer, how can I find the movie title or topic in a structured format, and other interesting metadata such as the celebrities featured or the director?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. The v3 API allows you do do this via [videos/list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/list?hl=de). Here's an example API call using a trailer for The Dark Knight Rises:

GET https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?part=topicDetails&id=g8evyE9TuYk&fields=items%2FtopicDetails%2FtopicIds&key={YOUR_API_KEY}

(To get a developer key, follow the instructions in our [video tutorial](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Im69kzhpR3I&list=PLhBgTdAWkxeB-zCekGukAo0DzmpwBiua2&index=1)).

That sets:

topic: topicDetails
id: g8evyE9TuYk
fields: items/topicDetails/topicIds

In the response body, you get:

```
{
 "items": [
  {
   "topicDetails": {
    "topicIds": [
     "/m/0bpm4yw",
     "/m/01d5g",
     "/m/0btpm6",
     "/m/0184dt",
     "/m/02vxn"
    ]
   }
  }
 ]
}
```

These correspond to Freebase mids, which you can lookup using the [Freebase API](http://wiki.freebase.com/wiki/Freebase_API). For instance, the first response corresponds to the [Freebase entity The Dark Knight Rises (movie)](http://www.freebase.com/m/0bpm4yw). Once you look up the entity, you can look up related entities such as the director, actors, or genre.

Play around with the API explorer a bit. When you're ready to translate this into code, watch out video about turning the [API reference into code](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GNRMeaz6QRI&list=PLhBgTdAWkxeCMHYCQ0uuLyhydRJGDRNo5).

Comment: Thanks. watching the video now. is that you in the video as well?

Comment: If you have a need for summary information about a topic, the Freebase Topic API a good way to get it all in one go. e.g. the example movie is https://www.googleapis.com/freebase/v1/topic/m/0bpm4yw which returns a big chunk of JSON data with all the relevant info.  This is overkill if you just want e.g. the name and release date, but otherwise is a nice convenience.  For a briefer version, append ?filter=suggest (Suggest is the autocomplete widget)

Comment: Yep, that's me in the video. Shameless self promotion =). Thanks for the tip, Tom!

Comment: @IkaiLan: Regarding these topic ids being associated with each video, are these topics provided by the user ?
Or there isa team at Youtube/Google responsible for adding related freebase topics to videos or that is also automated ?

Comment: This is automated. There's a Google IO talk about how these tags are generated http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wf_77z1H-vQ

Comment: I also get something like /g/122l8byq, /g/121_bxwg, g/15dqd3lz, /g/1222zn1t ... as topicIds, what are these???????

Answer (score 2):

I found that I got the metadata details I wanted via this request url:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?part=snippet,contentDetails&id={YouTubeVideoID}&key={YourAPIkey}
```

[Here is documentation](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos?hl=de) with description of all the returned data fields.

[Here's info on how to get an API key.](https://developers.google.com/youtube/registering_an_application)